# Javascript filter array based on another array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to merge the two arrays based on `Arr1` values. If the array 2 doesn't has the respective value in `array1`, it should return as empty object with values. Below are the two arrays:

```
Arr1 = [{
  name: "raj",
  age: 20
}, {
  name: "ravi",
  age: 40
}];


Arr2 = ['raj', 'ravi', 'arnold'];
```

Javascript Code is,

```
let result = Arr1.filter(o1 => Arr2.some(o2 => o2 === o1.name));
```

I am getting the result as below,

```
result = [{
  name: "raj",
  age: 20
}, {
  name: "ravi",
  age: 40
}];
```

But expected array should be,

```
[{
  name: "raj",
  age: 20
}, {
  name: "ravi",
  age: 40
}, {
 name: "arnold",
 age: null,
 available: no
}];
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array#map` along with `Array#find` to obtain your expected result.

```js
let Arr1 = [{
  name: "raj",
  age: 20
}, {
  name: "ravi",
  age: 40
}];
let Arr2 = ['raj', 'ravi', 'arnold'];
let result = Arr2.map(x=>
     Arr1.find(({name})=>name===x)??{name:x,age:null,available: 'no'}
  );
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @GTemp No problem.

Comment: yes. stack overflow asking to wait to accept correct answer min 2mins. :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a different approach and take an object for the given data and map the wanted names for eithe the given data or a new object.

This approach has a better big O, becaus it take a hash table and works fast for great data.

```js
const
    array1 = [{ name: "raj", age: 20 }, { name: "ravi", age: 40 }],
    array2 = ['raj', 'ravi', 'arnold'],
    data = array1.reduce((r, o) => (r[o.name] = o, r), {}),
    result = array2.map(name => data[name] || { name, age: null, available: 'no' });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```